typescript: "property does not exist on type" and "hasOwnProperty"
I have a piece of data with type:
type OptionType = {value: number | string} | number | string


I'm trying to access the value with:
const finalValue = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(data, "value") ? value.value : value;

But typescript throws:

Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string | number | OptionType'

Anyone know how to fix this?
